# How come all of my objects are just outlines?

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]

I opened Blender today and all of my objects on all of my files are this kind of invisible where I can still see the outline. When I make new files the issue persists and when I go into edit mode I can still see the vertices. I know the objects aren't hidden and I can't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: You might want to state what type of video card you have.  Numerous problems in that area.

Comment: Seconded - Latest AMD Adrenalin drivers are causing problems in blender. Reverting to an older driver version usually solves it.

Comment: sry knittpicky here ^^ .. you also may want to change your titel.. you want to *find* the reason so you can fix it.. so there definitly is a reason. Genneraly descriptice titels work best. Maybee lock at https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChristopherBennett It's probably that, I'm using a Radeon RX 580 and I updated my driver last night, thanks for the help!