# Problem with Viewport shading not displaying my models

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shaders

Today Ive gotten a problem with my viewport shading.

If I work in "**Display in solid mode**" the models are showing corectlly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOTVL.jpg
But if I change to "**Material preview mode**" or " **Rendered**" my models go "grey as the background" invisible.
No textures and no colors showing.(attached photos).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKAn9.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1HGV.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d7OQ.jpg
[image]

I had used Blender a lot on my system previously and never had this problem, also when I copy the same files to a different computer the viewport shading is showing the models correctly.
I had searched litteraly all day if anybody had a similiar problem with no luck.
Also I had reinstall my drivers, tried different versions of Blender, tried different project files, tried Blender demo files, also I have tried to reset Blender config to default and to install blender to another disk. Nothing worked.
It is also the same if I use eevee or cyclees. (Only difference is that it somehow renders in Cycles normally).
Am I missing something obvious? I really cant get viewport to be showing my models normal again.
I appreciate all the help.

**FIXED: It was a Radeon graphic card driver problem. I downgraded to 20.9.2 and it works now like a charm.**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/how-come-all-of-my-objects-are-just-outlines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204687/eevee-rendering-materials-dont-work

Comment: Do you happen have to an AMD gpu? They are having alot of issues lately it seems.