# Issues with Viewport and Evee render, not sure if it's a setting or a bug I have

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Beginner here so I'm not even sure if this issue is because of a setting I have, or if it's a bug. So when I change viewports, I noticed the that the last two options just give me a greyed out image. Even in older projects I have which used to render correctly, it would give a trippy image. Tried recording my issue hopefully it helps!

https://streamable.com/7msx0z

This happens in Evee, but I also noticed that even in cycles, it would render it like this:

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/how-come-all-of-my-objects-are-just-outlines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204687/eevee-rendering-materials-dont-work

Comment: Yeah kind of! Now I know it's a driver issue haha thanks a lot! I can't really roll back right now, but I did discover another fix for it, I'll update my post.