# Everything is invisible in material and in render preview

Tags: rendering

[image]

I am semi-new to blender and just got the new version. For some reason, everything is invisible in material mode and render preview. And this is not just a "you messed up the texture" problem. Even in the default startup file, everything is invisible. I rendered a short animation to see if it was just a viewport glitch, but no. Even when rendered nothing shows except for a few pink objects that have no texture.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please [edit] your question and add images of your interface. Are using cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/how-come-all-of-my-objects-are-just-outlines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204687/eevee-rendering-materials-dont-work