# When spawning an object in blender its invisible

Tags: objects

When i spawn in an object in 2.82.7 with a plugin/script or while clicking the button the object is invisible here is an example of a spawned in sphere while its selected

[image]

1. There is no need for lights because im in "solid mode"
2. When unselected the object is completely invisible (there is no outline)

Now the only way i found to fix this is i switch from "object mode" into "edit mode" and the moment i do that this happens

[image]

This also works if i press this button

[image]

If i switch back to "object mode" or disable the icon above it returns back to being invisible and the only way i found to make it visible is if im in "edit mode" (or the icon from above is activated) and then i deselect the object (by left clicking on empty space) and after that going in "object mode"
Here are all the steps in picture form

Deselect

[image]

object mode after deselecting

[image]

and now the object is visible and the "icon" from above is not active now

here is an example

[image]

if i select something that isnt an object or camera and go to "edit mode" and do all of the steps it doesnt work

also if i go back to "edit mode" and select a face and go to "object mode" without unselecting it it turns invisible

example

[image]

[image]

btw if i go up to a higher version of blender for example 2.9 then blender doesnt start for me but crashes on the "start screen" the like "command window" with all of the "words" before it would launch

I have an AMD processor and an AMD graphics card

Comment: How would i enable High Quality Normals because i dont see the "Performance" section in the render settings @Gorgious

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/how-come-all-of-my-objects-are-just-outlines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204687/eevee-rendering-materials-dont-work

Comment: @Hellcat_destroyer Try switching the render engine to Eevee

Comment: @Gorgious both in eevee and cycles there is no option to enable "High Quality Normals" in eevee there isnt even a "Performance" section in cycles there is a "Performance" section but not the option to enable "High Quality Normals"

Comment: @Timaroberts the only problem i have is the one i stated none of the other problems are existent for me

Comment: @Hellcat_destroyer Have you updated your GPU drivers lately? If yes, then roll them back as noted in the solutions mentioned in the linked questions.

Comment: @Timaroberts that would probably fix it but if "recently" means in the middle of this year then yes i updated them then and then i checked for updates recently and there is no newer version so in short that would probably fix it but im looking for a better solution that doesnt include reverting my whole graphics software to an older less good version so thats why im asking about the "Performance" section cause that would be easier and more effective

Comment: Use the latest 2.83 version

Comment: @Gorgious will do

Comment: @Gorgious im back sorry for the long wait but it doesnt fix the problem its okay tho its not rly a big problem its just slightly annoying just saying this so it doesnt seem i just disappeared after saying that without an answer to the fix