# wireframe is invisible and only the outline is visible. in object mode

Tags: wireframe

In Edit mode, the object looks normal. but in Object mode, the wireframe is not visible and only the outline is visible.

I downgraded the graphics card because I thought it might be a problem, but there is still a problem.
By the way, rendering works normally.

I tried reinstalling the blender and graphics driver, but the problem remains the same.

Now version is 'RadeonSoftwareAdrenalin2020 20.11.2'

Upgraded version is '20.12.1'

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204044/viewports-broken-on-rx-580 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204897/how-come-all-of-my-objects-are-just-outlines https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204687/eevee-rendering-materials-dont-work

Comment: it looks like some manage to fix this with the High Quality Normals option in the Render Panel > Performance

Comment: Downgrading to Adrenaline 20.9.2 ensures normal wireframe operation. Thank you.